# npm 2 и 3 версии

Tags: node.js, npm

Обновил npm до 3 версии и заметил разницу в расположении пакетов.
В проекте, раньше к примеру было так, в node_modules, каждая установка 
создает папку и ставит свои зависимости к себе в node_modules рекурсивно.

```
node_modules/
├── autoprefixer-loader
├── babel-core
├── babel-loader
├── css-loader
├── extract-text-webpack-plugin
├── jade
├── jade-loader
├── less
├── less-loader
├── lodash
├── style-loader
├── webpack
└── webpack-dev-server
```

на 3 же версии, все пакеты и зависимости, сыпятся в одну корневую node_modules
Это какой то баг или что? как это можно исправить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это особенность npm 3. Теперь все пакеты (в том числе их зависимости) устанавливаются непосредственно в node_modules. Также изменилась логика работы с `peerDependencies`. Теперь модули из этого поля не устанавливаются автоматически. npm выведет предупреждение, если один из таких модулей ещё не установлен.
Сделано это всё для борьбы с дубликатами.